# struts2: What is the max session data?

Tags: java, session, struts2

We are developing one social networking site, which has to maintain lot of data for notification (unreal notification, which is nothing but the notification for the activities done when the user is not logged in).

Once the user logs in we will be fetching lot of data in the form of `JSON`. There will be around around `JSON` objects, each `JSON` will inturn consist of min 1000 characters, this data must be available in all pages the user navigates, so we are keeping all the data in the session.

How feasible it is to keep such data in session?

Is there any limit for the amount data we store in session?

Keeping huge data may sometime lead to hinder the performance of the application.

What is the most optimized way of handling such data if this is not the proper one?

Comment: 1k is almost nothing. Obviously there are limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is there any limit for the amount data we store in session?
```

There is no limit how much data you put in your session, but there is only limit of space in your computer.

But,

To put lot of data in session lead performance degradation of system,

you can do one thing use temporary database table which will keep only values that use required when he navigate through application and the populate each time when user visit that particular page. I think round-trip no more costly then session in your scenario.